# OpenGL: how to draw a rectangle without a perfect shape?

Tags: opengl, shapes

For example, when we draw a rectangle manually, it is not perfect. 
There might be some bumps along the lines.

By using OpenGL, how can we draw a rectangle without a perfect shape?

It is like to just some noise, but noise to the shape.

I have a rough idea: we have a perfect grid, and some distortion to the grid.
Then the rectangle will distort based on the distorted grid.

Any thoughts or links?

Comment: This looks somewhat vague to be a good fit for SO. The simplest approach I can think of is to subdivide each line that defines a side into smaller line segments, and then apply a randomized offset to each intermediate point.

Comment: Distorting geometry is a possibility but that is limited to Vertex dense geometries (or need to create it in geometry shader) which will negatively impact on performance. Instead I would try: blending with some Alpha texture, or add noise to borders in fragment (discarting fragments).